# convert mongodb command to doctrine format Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence

Please how do I express the following in my symfony script.
I have a repository defined as below:

```
$repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()->getRepository('MyMpBundle:Scripts');
```

What I need is to get the values of columns (fields) in a Document where a field (user_id) is given (in my case user_id=1) and display the results in array. In MySQL this would be something like: select * from Scripts where user_id = 1;

I have tried the following but I get empty coily brackets as result.

```
$script = $repository->findOneBy(array('user_id' => 1));
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(json_encode($script));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

Any help pls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out json_encode works for public (not private and protected). There might be a workaround this but for now I have changed the fields to public and it works.

Comment: Mark your own answer as accepted so that when other users are searching for unresolved questions, yours won't show up.